# IllegalAnnotationExceptions in the MemberSubmissionEndpointReference class

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

I have been fighting with this problem for 2 days now. I need help

I am running Spring mvc and everything looks. I add the client of another webservice as dependency and then when I try to test, I get this exception.

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "address". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address
        at public com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.addr
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address
        at private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.address
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference
Two classes have the same XML type name "elements". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Elements
        at public com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Elements com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.referenceProperties
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements
        at private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.referenceParameters
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference
```

Doing further analysis, I see that these conflicting (address/element) exist in the class **com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference**  which belongs one of my dependencies

```
<groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
<version>2.2.5</version>
```

And the other class **javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference** it belongs to is probably in the client that I have in my dependency.

How can I fix this issue!! they are not my classes so I can't modify them. I am not sure what to do. I tried exclusions, binding ..etc and nothing worked

**EDIT:**

I am using Eclipse for IDE and websphere as application server . Here are the 2 xml dependencies that are in conflict

```
XML1:
<groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
<version>2.2.5</version>

XML2:
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

If I upgrade xml1 to 2.3.5 then the issue is gone but the problem is 2.3.5 is complied in Java 8 and the rest of my app is Java 7 (I am locked by work to it) and it is throwing compatibility error. So I am looking for other ways to fix it

Comment: is it possible for you to post maven dependencies?

Comment: I think everyone could be a better help if you post. What is your IDE, Application Server, and your pom.xml with the supposed conflicting dependencies

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah Please see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependencies conflict. 
I can not tell exact solution until you post full pom.xml, but here is how I would solve that: 
in `intellij idea ide` install "Maven Helper" plugin, restart IDE, open pom and on the bottom open `dependency analizer` tab. There you have conflicts and an easy way to exclude conflicting packages with 1 click.

[here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/167922?_sscc=t) guy had same problem, and he went through filtering jars with hands, one by one.

UPD. also found [this issue](https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws/issues/1098), didn't you try to increase version of that lib to the latest `2.3.2`? (seems to be fixed in `2.2.8`)

Comment: Hello, I know where conflict is from but I don't know how to fix it. Like I said the jaxws-rt 2.2.5 (or 2.2.8) has one class that is conflicting with the client library Iam (the client library code is generated using JAX-WS RI 2.2.10). The link you shared is for Metro which I am not using The issue essentially is a conflict between IBM implementation and Sun implementation

Comment: Did you try an approach with maven helper plugin that I pointed?

Comment: The thing is that I am using eclipse. I don't have much flexibility installing a new IDE as it is work computer.  Is there an equivalant thing in eclipse?

Comment: By the way, if I use version 2.3.2 the issue disappears but then I get an error during startup complaining about version incompatibility (My websphere is running 1.7 but the library is in 1.8). I don't know how to go beyond that

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem is conflicting `jaxws-api` which contains `W3CEndpointReference` which has `static Address` method.

`jaxws-rt` contains `jaxws-api` so, I suggest to go to `Dependency Hierarchy` in Eclipse and check which artifacts are using `jaxws-api` and try excluding it from the one that you think you don't need.

On a side note `jaxws-rt` contains `MemberSubmissionEndpointReference` which also contains `Address` as a member. So, possible solution worth trying is to exclude `jaxws-api` from `jaxws-rt` but then your `jaxws-rt` may not work as expected.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of excluding it, I was getting different error for the excluded library so I this option does not work. I can't seem to find any other library using jaxws-api

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to add those apis as dependencies in your pom.xml. There are already included in the JDK by default (rt.jar). I don't see in which case you need to define them as dependencies in your pom.xml.

Besides in the source code of those classes there are different namespaces declared which avoir those elements conflicts :

In `MemberSubmissionEndpointReference`

```
@XmlElement(
    name = "Address",
    namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
)
public MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.Address addr;
```

And in `W3CEndpointReference`

```
private W3CEndpointReference.Address address;
@XmlElement(
    name = "ReferenceParameters",
    namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
)
```

So the question is, why are up loading those dependency direclty in your pom.xml?

**EDIT 2 : ASSUMING YOU HAVE TO KEEP YOUR CURRENT DEPENDENCIES**

You seem to want to upload two versions of the same webapp with slight differences.

You can do what is advised in this [JBoss AS Thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/167922), keep the minimal Jars in your websphere in order to keep you app running.

As well as a more complex task. What role do these classes and apis play in your app ?

Comment: These are existing fairly large projects. When I removed them, crashes during startup happened left and right and the service never started.

Comment: When checking thoses classes in your project code source. do they point to rt.jar in JDK 7 or the point to the dependencies your posted ?

Comment: How can I double check? Searching a file does not search dependency of dependency (Dependency 2 is coming from the POM file of a dependency)